# Prisma explicit many to many field already defined

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I have comics which has many writers, artists and characters and i'm trying to join everything together in prisma, but struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comic schema:

```
model comics {
  uniqueCoverId             String                    @id
  name                      String
  artists                   comic_contributors[]   @relation("artists")
  writers                   comic_contributors[]   @relation("writers")
}
```

Artists schema

```
model comic_artists {
  id                       String                    @id @default(uuid())
  name                     String?
  comics                   comic_contributors[]
}
```

Writers schema

```
model comic_writers {
  id     String                    @id @default(uuid())
  name   String?
  comics comic_contributors[]
}
```

Intermediary table

```
model comic_contributors {
  writer_id String              @unique
  writer    comic_writers? @relation("writers", fields: [writer_id], references: [id])

  artist_id String              @unique
  artist    comic_artists? @relation("artists", fields: [artist_id], references: [id])

  @@id([writer_id, artist_id])
}
```

When I try to format prisma it returns the errors

```
error: Field "comics" is already defined on model "comic_contributors".
comicsUniqueCoverId String?
comics              comics?        @relation(fields: [comicsUniqueCoverId], references: [uniqueCoverId])


error: Field "comicsUniqueCoverId" is already defined on model "comic_contributors".
comics              comics?        @relation(fields: [comicsUniqueCoverId], references: [uniqueCoverId])
comicsUniqueCoverId String?
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicit a [many-to-many](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations) relationship table, Prisma is doing it for you!

**[Prisma implicit many-to-many](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations)**

You only have to say:

```js
model comics {
  uniqueCoverId String          @id
  name          String
  artists       comic_artists[]
  writers       comic_writers[]
}

model comic_artists {
  id     String   @id @default(uuid())
  name   String?
  comics comics[]
}

model comic_writers {
  id     String   @id @default(uuid())
  name   String?
  comics comics[]
}
```

and Prisma will create hidden relationship tables as
`_comic_artitsTocomics`

```
column A -> comic_artits.id
column B -> comics.uniqueCoverId
```

`_comic_writersTocomics`

```
column A -> comic_writers.id
column B -> comics.uniqueCoverId
```

This allow you to do

```js
const comic = await prisma.comics.findUnique({
  where: {
    uniqueCoverId: 'UniqueCoverId',
  },
  include: {
    artists: true,
    writers: true,
  },
});
```

And `comic` will looks like

```js
{
  uniqueCoverId: 'UniqueCoverId',
  name: 'Name',
  artists: [
    { id: '210059e6-00ab-448c-aea9-b706251ade52', name: 'Artist1' },
    { id: '38cd8efa-2a66-4fe5-ad47-ec4f511647c0', name: 'Artist2' },
    { id: '86d6c908-f17b-4fbd-b0ee-c314f06aeaa9', name: 'Artist3' }
  ],
  writers: [
    { id: '9cf97bf4-9c43-4579-924b-15a7f5dcb3f9', name: 'Writer1' },
    { id: 'afe6eb2d-6d69-44f2-a491-14827dc94e66', name: 'Writer2' },
    { id: 'cdac61cf-339d-460d-960b-6581fa2d7a57', name: 'Writer3' }
  ]
}
```

**[Prisma explicit many-to-many](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#explicit-many-to-many-relations)**

But if you really need an explicit many-to-many relationship to add some data on the relation it will looks like this schema

```js
model comics {
  uniqueCoverId String                  @id
  name          String
  artists       comic_artistsOncomics[]
  writers       comic_writersOncomics[]
}

model comic_artists {
  id     String                  @id @default(uuid())
  name   String?
  comics comic_artistsOncomics[]
}

model comic_artistsOncomics {
  uniqueCoverId String
  comic         comics        @relation(fields: [uniqueCoverId], references: [uniqueCoverId])
  artistId      String
  artist        comic_artists @relation(fields: [artistId], references: [id])
  // Some data

  @@id([uniqueCoverId, artistId])
}

model comic_writers {
  id     String                  @id @default(uuid())
  name   String?
  comics comic_writersOncomics[]
}

model comic_writersOncomics {
  uniqueCoverId String
  comic         comics        @relation(fields: [uniqueCoverId], references: [uniqueCoverId])
  writerId      String
  writer        comic_writers @relation(fields: [writerId], references: [id])
  // Some data

  @@id([uniqueCoverId, writerId])
}
```

The previous [findUnique](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#findunique) will now looks like

```js
  const test = await prisma.comics.findUnique({
    where: {
      uniqueCoverId: 'uniqueCoverId',
    },
    include: {
      artists: {
        include: {
          artist: true,
        },
      },
      writers: {
        include: {
          writer: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

And the result

```
{
  uniqueCoverId: "UniqueCoverId",
  name: "Name",
  artists: [
    {
      uniqueCoverId: "UniqueCoverId",
      artistId: "210059e6-00ab-448c-aea9-b706251ade52",
      artist: {
        id: "210059e6-00ab-448c-aea9-b706251ade52",
        name: "Artist1",
      },
    },
    {
      uniqueCoverId: "UniqueCoverId",
      artistId: "38cd8efa-2a66-4fe5-ad47-ec4f511647c0",
      artist: {
        id: "38cd8efa-2a66-4fe5-ad47-ec4f511647c0",
        name: "Artist2",
      },
    },
    {
      uniqueCoverId: "UniqueCoverId",
      artistId: "86d6c908-f17b-4fbd-b0ee-c314f06aeaa9",
      artist: {
        id: "86d6c908-f17b-4fbd-b0ee-c314f06aeaa9",
        name: "Artist3",
      },
    },
  ],
  writers: [
    {
      uniqueCoverId: "UniqueCoverId",
      writerId: "9cf97bf4-9c43-4579-924b-15a7f5dcb3f9",
      writer: {
        id: "9cf97bf4-9c43-4579-924b-15a7f5dcb3f9",
        name: "Writer1",
      },
    },
    {
      uniqueCoverId: "UniqueCoverId",
      writerId: "afe6eb2d-6d69-44f2-a491-14827dc94e66",
      writer: {
        id: "afe6eb2d-6d69-44f2-a491-14827dc94e66",
        name: "Writer2",
      },
    },
    {
      uniqueCoverId: "UniqueCoverId",
      writerId: "cdac61cf-339d-460d-960b-6581fa2d7a57",
      writer: {
        id: "cdac61cf-339d-460d-960b-6581fa2d7a57",
        name: "Writer3",
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

**EDIT FOR YOU TO TEST**

```js
model comics {
  id            String          @id @default(uuid())
  uniqueCoverId String          @unique
  name          String
  artists       comic_artists[]
  writers       comic_writers[]
}

model comic_artists {
  id     String   @id @default(uuid())
  name   String?
  comics comics[]
}

model comic_writers {
  id     String   @id @default(uuid())
  name   String?
  comics comics[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment/investigation! I did try implicit approach but it was returning an error to me ` Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`, so I thought I would try the explicit approach to dictate the name... however it turns out, your solution works, but i'm left with the same error. Others suggest innoDB but this isn't an option for me. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's your `uniqueCoverId` that it too long? You should try with a `id String @id @default(uuid())` and set your `uniqueCoverId` as unique instead of id `uniqueCoverId String @unique`

Comment: I just edit the end of the post with this modification, could you test it?

Comment: thank you I've accepted your answer - I ended up switching to InnoDB engine and that resolved the issue